# How to get the Values in form without submitting it?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have this form in which I need data of $availableVehicles according to the eventDate. I want to pass this value of eventDate to controller. So that I ll get the values of $availableVehicles in my form. Please suggest me right approach to get data. I don't need query. I have query I just want to pass the variable eventDate in that. I am getting the values form values from @create  and form will be submitted at @store. I want to send the value of eventDate at create and after getting data from query @create in form I ll submit that data to @store.

```html
{!!Form::open(['action' => 'BookingsController@store', 'method' => 'POST'])!!}
    @csrf
    <input type="date" name="eventDate" id="eventDate" value="">
    <select name="vehicleName" id="vehicleName">
        <option disabled selected>Choose Vehicle...</option>
        <?php foreach ($availableVehicles as $key => $vehicle): ?>
            <option id="{{$vehicle->id}}">{{$vehicle->name}} </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Comment: Read the [documentation on retrieving input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input)

Comment: @Ali Anwar: Please show your code and may be you need eventDate value?

Comment: In your `BookingsController` create a method `public function store(Request $req) {}` then inside that method the code `$req-> eventDate` should contain the value from the form.

Answer (score 2):

In your bookingController create the following method:

```
public function store(Request $request){
$event_date = $request->input('eventDate');
}
```

Then you can use the $event_date variable to do whatever you want. For more information see the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests)

Comment: I have created controller. Problem is how to pass eventDate in controller, We cannot submit the form  @store until we get the value according to the eventDate.

Answer (score 2):

In controller you can get values like @Nabil has suggested to you, but I have not seen id in options of select tag, I mean this

```
   <option id="{{$vehicle->id}}">{{$vehicle->name}} </option>
```

It should be like this to get it's value

```
    <option value="{{$vehicle->id}}">{{$vehicle->name}} </option>
```

And Further more you can also do this to get date related values from table in your database

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
    $vehicles = new vehicle; //vehicle is a model name
    $this->validate($request,[
        'vehiclename'=>'required',
        'eventDate'=>'required'
    ]);
    $vehicles->vehiclename = $request->vehicleName;
    $vehicles->eventdate= $request->eventDate;
    $vehicles->save();
    return redirect("/");
}
```

in `where()` condition eventdate should be same as it is in database

In your create method you can do this to get all values from database and assign to your home view page

```
   public function create()
 {
    $vehicles = \DB::table('DatabaseTableName')->all();
                OR
    $vehicles = modelname::all();
    return view("home",compact('vehicles'));
 }
```

And then in home page do this `{{$vehicles->name}}` etc
`modelname` means you have to create model for you database table if you don't how to create model then use first option with tablename

Comment: Brother I ve created my query in the Controller. I ve to get values from public function create() and Submit at @store. How I can I send/pass the value of eventDate in create to get the values availableVehicles accordingly. I cannot submit form at that level. Form will be submitted store() at later stage.

Comment: Bro show me your create function so that i can guide you further

Comment: if you are using resource routes and you have many functions like create index etc in a controller and you want to pass values to your page, let say home page then see the updated answer.

Comment: Nothing to do with controllers they are fine. Question is how the value in the form that is named as eventDate can b sent without submitting the form. I know we can make get request but here it is not possible because the form will be submitted somewhere else. You have nothing to do with storing of form or submit. I have a question I dont want to submit the form. And I want to change the dropdowns that are linked to database with onchange or etc function.

Comment: Then you have to send the id in a route and then fetch it's related eventDate from database, once you get you can submit the form later, i think u mean this

Comment: you can also use JavaScript or jQuery code to change dropdowns or anything you like